# Как быстр конвертировать сайт в приложение?

Tags: android, windows, ios

Как конвертировать мобильную версию сайта в приложение для моб. устройств?
То есть фактически нужен браузер, который будет открывать предустановленную главную ссылку. Есть ли подобные сервисы? Или это несложно сделать самостоятельно? Благодарен за любой совет или помощь!

Comment: Если нужен браузер с предустановленной ссылкой, вот видео как сделать - может подойдет.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4-ZqnxGFgw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фактически Вам нужно приложение, которое запускает компонент Webview с предустановленным URL.

Вот пошаговая инструкция для Android Studio https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 2):

Ознакомьтесь с [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/guide/platforms/android/), думаю то что вам подойдет.

Comment: Регистрируйтесь тут https://phonegap.com/
Качайте их клиент, создаете новое приложение "Hello world".
В html-ке меняете "Hello world" на ваш сайт. Стили кладете или в папку с ассетами, или делаете инлайн, картинки в ассеты. Билдите приложение с помощью https://build.phonegap.com/ в готовые приложения. Это самый простой способ для новичка. Можно, как и писалось выше с помощью Андроид студии

Answer (score 0):

Спустя год поиска нашел [Alstrapp CMS](http://ru.alstrapp.com).
С помощью этого скрипта получилось создать приложение для своего сайта.